# get Layer Id of a specific Marker

Tags: leaflet

I have polygons represented in Leaflet.
Then I added some markers over these Polygons.

```
var = customMarker = L.Marker.extend({
    options:{
        Layer: ''
    }});
```

I extended marker to store the layer ID of my polygon.
How can I know which what is the Layer ID of my Marker?

Comment: Do you mean the unique id of the marker layer? try marker._leaflet_id

Comment: I mean the Id of the layer that the marker belongs to. In other words, which polygon (ID) contains the marker.

Comment: If you are creating your points/markers in leaflet you can probably add the polygon._leaflet_id during the layerGroup creation. If the marker's dataset is external - you can use  Ray Casting algorithm to determine the containing polygon and get its id [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon)